# Datameer partition filter expression to specify 2 Months

Tags: database

I need dynamic data partition for my datameer workbook. I need two months of data from today. So if i go to Advance partition filtering and specify something like $partition > TODAY()-60d && $partition <= TODAY() , it isn't getting me full 60 days of data. Couldn't see any examples on how to use MONTH in datameer documentation. Any help is appreciated.
I use datameer version 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"For this particular use case, I'd recommend the following Advanced Partition Filter:

$partition >= STARTOFMONTH(ADDTODATE(TODAY();"-2M"))

To break this down, the formula's core starts with the same TODAY() calculation and then uses the ADDTODATE function to go to the date 2 months ago ("-2M"). After this, the STARTOFMONTH function is used to ensure that the first of the month is referenced to align with the partition definition. "